# Как работают Firebase уведомления?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notification

Неделю не могу сделать. Это просто ужас. Создал в Firebase проект Films, указал только package. Создал само приложение:

Манифест:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lovemusic.films">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/toolbar_bg" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label=""/>

    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen"
        android:name=".BannerActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:name=".StreamActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseIDService">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

FirebaseService

```
public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    }
}
```

FirebaseIDService

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
    }
}
```

Отправляю уведомление из консоли и они не приходят, хотя статус: отправлено. Что мне делать? Я еще не понимаю каким образом приложение будет ловить пуши, если никаких апи ключей нет? Вообще непонятный сервис. Обьясните на пальцах кому не лень.. Спасибо

Comment: Это костыль какой-то... Огромный

Comment: Там либо надо указывать ключ устройства, либо отправлять в "topic", но тогда надо в приложении на этот топик подписаться

Comment: API ключи содержатся в файле google-services.json, который надо скачать из консоли Firebase и включить в проект

Comment: @rjhdby, скачал, положил рядом с `src`. Это все? Или в манифесте надо еще что-то?

Comment: собственно я делал ровно по этому мануалу https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup и проблем небыло от слова совсем

Comment: @rjhdby, я ничего не понимаю( все же есть. Что еще надо?

Comment: При запуске активности что-то запускать?

Comment: А если при старте приложения внимательно лог посмотреть, там ругани от firebase нет?

Comment: @rjhdby, `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58193/discussion-between-flippy-and-rjhdby).

Comment: Наверное пули не так отправляете. Покажите как вы это делаете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, перехожу на страницу создания уведомления и ввожу заголовок и текст. Нажимаю отправить сообщение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, на тестируемом устройстве нет сервисом Google Play, ни плэй сторе, ничего из GApps. Это из-за этого? Если да, то поддерживать устройства без сервисов не получится?

Comment: Ну да, без Gaps оно работать не должно никак. Также вы не раскрыли как токен девайса получаете для отсулки пуша. Или типа на все девайсы разом?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, токен? Ничего я не делаю такого. Два сервиса с переопределенными методами и все, пустые, обьявил их в манифесте + google-services.json. значит всетки ставить гапсы?

Comment: Да, насколько я понимаю без них оно работать не может.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58206/discussion-between-flippy-and-).

Comment: Поставил гапсы но теперь от `FirebaseApp` идет такой лог: `Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId`. А от непонятного `A4GCM` вообще вот это: `java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE`